# Dialogflow context lifespan expires before 20 mins

Tags: dialogflow-es

According to the Dialogflow [documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts/input-output-contexts#lifespan) by default, output contexts expire after either five requests or 20 mins after its corresponding intent is matched.

But when I'm trying this out (2nd request and the lifespan of the particular context was 5) I observed that this is less than 20 mins. When I tried after **11 mins** it is already expired. I'm using an Enterprise Bot of V2.

I'm experiencing 10 mins context expiration time. What is the actual expiration time of a context?

Comment: i am also experiencing the same 10 mins limit. i sent the support team an email as well, they stated it is indeed **20 mins**.

Comment: A person from Dialogflow support team replied to me as "I have raised this problem you've reported to our engineers and they are taking action to fix this issue. I'll get back to you once I have an update. Apologize for the inconvenience."

Which means that they have an issue from their end.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://blog.dialogflow.com/post/how-contexts-and-followup-intents-work/) blog post from DialogFlow, apparently the contexts are only supposed to last 10 minutes.